In my Food ordering app which is built in reactJS, I am getting an CORS error in fetching swiggy's API.(It is a frontend project)
I can resolve this issue by using the CORS Chrome extension. However, in that case, the app will work only on localhost. It will not work after deployment.
API I am using: https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=18.97210&lng=72.82460&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING.
import RestaurantCard, { withPromotedLabel } from "./RestaurantCard";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Shimmer from "./Shimmer";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import useOnlineStatus from "../utils/useOnlineStatus";
import UserContext from "../utils/UserContext";

const Body = () => {
    const [listOfRestaurants, setListOfRestaurants] = useState([]);
    const [filteredRestaurant, setFilteredRestaurant] = useState([]);
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

    const RestaurantCardPromoted = withPromotedLabel(RestaurantCard);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(
            "https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=18.97210&lng=72.82460&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING"
        );
        const json = await data.json();
        setListOfRestaurants(json?.data?.cards[4]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
        setFilteredRestaurant(json?.data?.cards[4]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
    };

    const onlineStatus = useOnlineStatus();

    if (onlineStatus === false) {
        return (
            <h1>
                Looks like you're offline!! Please check your internet connection.
            </h1>
        );
    }

    const { loggedInUser, setUserName } = useContext(UserContext);

    // Conditional Rendering
    return listOfRestaurants.length === 0 ? <Shimmer /> : (
        <div className="body">
            <div className="filter flex">
                <div className="search m-4 p-4">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        data-testid="searchInput"
                        className="border border-solid border-black"
                        value={searchText}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setSearchText(e.target.value);
                        }}
                    />
                    <button
                        className="px-4 py-2 bg-green-100 m-4 rounded-lg"
                        onClick={() => {
                            const filteredRestaurant = listOfRestaurants.filter(
                                (res) =>   res.info.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())        
                            );
                            setFilteredRestaurant(filteredRestaurant);
                        }}
                    >
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="search m-4 p-4 flex items-center">
                    <button
                        className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg"
                        onClick={() => {
                            const filteredList = listOfRestaurants.filter(
                                (res) => res.info.avgRating > 4
                            );
                            setFilteredRestaurant(filteredList);
                        }}
                    >
                        Top Rated Restaurants
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div className="search m-4 p-4 flex items-center">
                    <label className="p-2 pl-4">UserName:</label>
                    <input
                        className="border border-black p-2"
                        value={loggedInUser}
                        onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Restaurant cards rendering */}
            <div className="restaurant-list">
                {filteredRestaurant.map((restaurant) => (
                    <Link to={`/restaurant/${restaurant.info.id}`} key={restaurant.info.id}>
                        {restaurant.info.veg ? (
                            <RestaurantCardPromoted resData={restaurant} />
                        ) : (
                            <RestaurantCard resData={restaurant} />
                        )}
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Body;




Is this a public API with documentation? Or are you trying to use their internal API that's made for their own use?

If the API is not for the public (Only for their company) and I checked there is no documentation related to it, I assumed you can't use the API. But, if you want to make sure, you can use a proxy in package.json like this:
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "proxy": "https://www.swiggy.com" // add this line
}

Edit:
After I tried to hit the API from Postman, it returned 403 Forbidden and I assumed it meant the API was only for their company
